# How to filter application insights logs based on log file type

Tags: azure, logging, application-insights

In a regular Sitecore deployment, the logs are written to files such as `Crawling.log.yyyyMMdd.txt` `Search.log.yyyyMMdd.txt` `log.yyyyMMdd.txt` and `Publishing.log.yyyyMMdd.txt`. When viewing logs in Azure Application Insights, is there some way to differentiate logs which would go into each of these different files?

Comment: I've also struggled a bit with App Insights, it seems a log harder to find log files for specific things. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I'd also like to see some improvement the way the logs are written in Azure, because currently they have a maximum size per file and logs get splitted to something like azure.log.20191025.124147.txt, azure.log.20191025.124147.txt.1, azure.log.20191025.124147.txt.2 and so on, but when you try to use Sitecore Log Analyzer (SCLA) you don't have all the results due to the files are splitted.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I understood from Application Insights, I made the below assumption which can help here.

1. Insights Trace= Log.Info, Publish log, search log, crawling log
2. Insights Avail= Azure all resource availability logs.
3. Insights Exception= Sitecore and other exception logs.
4. Insights Event= Operational logs for internal Sitecore operation from xConnect, xdb and other.

[image]

I am still struggling to get more deep knowledge of how we can distiguish different Sitecore logs in Systematic way in Application Insights.